# Is there a standard timeout value for TFTP?

Tags: tftp

I've reviewed [RFC 764](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1350) a number of times.  Even though it describes the timeout mechanism, there doesn't seem to mention any default timeout value.

Apparently, most implementations default to one second.  But ultimately, is there any *official* recommendation for the timeout value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a standardized TFTP timeout value.

RFC 1350 (The TFTP Protocol (Revision 2) does not specify a timeout value.

RFC 1784 (TFTP Timeout Interval and Transfer Size Options) define the Timeout as a negotiated parameter under the framework defined by RFC 1782 (TFTP Option Extension) but it does not define any particular value either.